# What is the purpose of header guards when there are multiple .cpp files that include that header file?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm taking the assumption that the header file has a function definition.

For a single translation unit, I understand that header files can prevent the same header file from being included multiple times, which can prevent compilation problems.

However, when there are multiple .cpp files using that header file, Those .cpp files would all be able to `#include` the header files, as the header guards `#define` would no longer be defined upon completing preprocessing of one file. This would cause the linker to complain as there would be a function redefinition. As such, I've seen that the recommended practice is to move the function definition into a .cpp file instead, so that such an issue would not occur.

But this would mean that that header file would no longer have function/variable definitions, and only declarations. As such, wouldn't header guards be rendered quite irrelevant in this case? Since multiple declarations are allowed, the multiple stacking of `#include` of that header file would not be an issue anymore.

Is there still a point to keeping the header guards in such a scenario?

Comment: Redeclaring a function with the same name is not a problem. Try adding a declaration for a class of the same name (and namespace) in the same translation unit multiple times and you've got a problem. Furthermore there can be scenarios where header files include each other which could result in infinite recursion of includes, if no header guards (or equivalent) are used...

Comment: *Is there still a point to keeping the header guards in such a scenario?* -- As soon as that header has something in it that *does* require guards to be used, you've just broken the build process.  Why chance things?  Just keep the header guards in -- there is no harm in doing so, and can cause all sorts of harm if left out.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't mention **circular includes** or **class definitions**?

Comment: Also possibly an issue: `constexpr` variables, `inline` functions, concepts

Comment: The possibilities of classes being redefined in a translation unit amongst all of this is something that completely slipped my mind, thanks!

Comment: @chrysante No code and seems opinion based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function/variable defined in a shared header must either be `static`, or `inline extern`. The `inline` and `extern` keyword migth sometimes  be optionally omited due to implication of context(in-class definition, `constexpr` specifier, template definition...). Otherwise, the program is ill-formed. Include guards are irrelevant to this issue.

Include guards(like any user defined macro) work at TU scope. So the definition of a macro in one TU has no direct correspondence to its definition in other TUs. It is possible to include a none guarded header in multiple TUs without any problem.

Main function of include guards is preventing multiple inclusions in same translation unit. Because multiple definitions in same TU is still ill-formed. One significant result of include guard is circular inclusion relaxation; without proper guards, that would result in infinite recursion, exhausting system resources before actually failing compilation.

Modern compilers introduce `#pragma once` as a one-liner alternative, yet I prefer include guards; the introduced guard macro can be used for conditional compilation.

By the way, I hope full `module` support becomes common among all platforms, So that these preprocessor hacks become less and less relevant.